# transferring files from server to local machine

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-10.04, linux, scp

Hello I am running ec2 ubuntu instance, now I need to download few files to my local ubuntu machine from my server. How to do it.

I went through few instructions available on internet, which are not working for me.

Kindly help me in this regard.I am pretty much aware of ssh/scp and rsync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scp [user]@server-ip:/path/to/file .

should do the job. it'll put it in current dir.

Comment: I have few php files in my server now I need to download that to my local system, how do I do that. I tried the command which u mentioned but its not working

Comment: /path/to/files/*.php .  is ssh working, and is scp allowed ? You can also do scp -r to copy a whole folder. Make sure the -r is before the rest of the command though.